# XPages appendDocLink on Anonymous User Error

Tags: xpages

I am attempting to replace my 'traditional Notes' User Name and Password Request form with one designed in XPages, mainly because the @SendMail Formula no longer works with Firefox or Chrome.

Anonymous users are to complete an XPage Form, hit a submit button which then sends an email to our support team, which is to include a Doc Link back to an internal Notes form of the same document, - I don't want to change this internal form as there is lots of lotusscript programming associated with it for processing.

I have the XPage marked as Available to Public Access as is the form associated with it. I also have ComputeWithForm set to both.

I can access the data document components e.g. append to the mail rtf body using doc.getItemValueString("field"), but I cannot do the same with appendDocLink it appears to fail due to access problems. If I set Anonymous to Manager access in the ACL the Doc link is appended.

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="button1" style="margin-top:50.0px">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="false" id="eventHandler1">
<xp:this.action>
<xp:actionGroup>
<xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
<xp:executeScript>
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript: if(document1.isNewNote()){document1.save();}
var doc:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
var receiverEmail = "Support Requests"; 
var requestor = "xyz@company.co.uk"; 
db = sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.getCurrentDatabase();
var memo = db.createDocument()
memo.appendItemValue("Form","Memo");
memo.appendItemValue("Principal","Company@NotesDomain");
memo.appendItemValue("From",requestor);
memo.appendItemValue("INetFrom",requestor);
memo.appendItemValue("DisplaySent",requestor);
memo.appendItemValue("SMTPOriginator",requestor);
memo.appendItemValue("Subject","NEW: Name & Password Request for "+getComponent("reqCompany1").getValue());
var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = memo.createRichTextItem("Body");
rtitem.addNewLine();
rtitem.appendText("A new Name & Password Request has been logged by "+getComponent("reqFirstName1").getValue()+" " + getComponent("reqSecondName1").getValue()+" of "+ getComponent("reqCompany1").getValue());
rtitem.addNewLine();
rtitem.appendText("Click the Doc link to action it. ");
rtitem.appendDocLink(doc);
memo.send(receiverEmail);}]]></xp:this.script>
                                </xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:openPage name="/UserNandPSubmitted.xsp"></xp:openPage>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
```

The following errors occur.

com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=25, col=8: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesRichTextItem.appendDocLink(lotus.domino.local.Document)
null

NotesException: Notes error: You are not authorized to perform that operation
    lotus.domino.local.RichTextItem.appendDocLink(Unknown Source)
    lotus.domino.local.RichTextItem.appendDocLink(Unknown Source)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way - another option is to call your code with sessionAsSigner.

Comment: @Frantisek I tried that, as in the code above and it didn't work Frantisek, have I correctly understood?

Comment: It should work. Probably signature problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21107992/206265 Or - and that can be question to IBM, appendDocLink does not count with signer session, who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Anonymous user can access the default view of the database - so make it accessible to public access users. appendDocLink() method requires this view in order to append doc link to RT item.

Comment: Many thanks, that works, is it not a security issue though, I don't want anonymous access to my default view?

Comment: The defaut view don't have to contain any data (define a stupid selection formula). Also add a $$ViewTemplateDefault form to restrict direct access to all views via URL.

Comment: As@OliverBusse said, data in it are not important, database just must define any default view. There is side effect for Notes users, though, so use frameset if you have Notes users.

Comment: Thank you Frantisek, yes I have Framesets so it works fine now.